# как в myqsl включить кириллицу

Tags: mysql, qt

Когда пишешь кириллицу появляются знаки ????
Попытался добавить следующий код:

```
       mysql_set_character_set(&mysql, "utf8");
       mysql_query(&mysql,"SET NAMES UTF8");
       mysql_query(&mysql,"SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
```

Но кириллица не заработала.

Вот весь код:

```
MYSQL mysql;
   mysql_init(&mysql);
   if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "", "", "test", 0, NULL, 0))
   {
   qDebug() << "Error: can'tconnecttodatabase\n" << mysql_error(&mysql);
   }
   else
   {
   qDebug() << "Success!\n";
   }
   mysql_set_character_set(&mysql, "utf8");
   mysql_query(&mysql,"SET NAMES UTF8");
   mysql_query(&mysql,"SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
   if (mysql_query(&mysql, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EventBalancer;") == 0)
   {
      int rows = static_cast<int>(mysql_affected_rows(&mysql ));
      if (rows == 0) {
         qDebug() << "Exists\n";
      }
      else {
        qDebug() <<"Created\n";

        if(mysql_query(&mysql, "USE EventBalancer;"))
         {
          qDebug() << mysql_error(&mysql);
         }

         if(mysql_query(&mysql, "CREATE TABLE EventBalancer (number INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, _date DATETIME NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(32), type VARCHAR(64));"))
         {
          qDebug() << mysql_error(&mysql);
         }
      }
   }
   mysql_close(&mysql);
```

Comment: При создании БД или Таблицы или Столбцов нужно указывать кодировку

Comment: @ ArchDemon прошу показать пример.